# Can I catch client disconnects on server-side using flask-uwsgi-websocket?

Tags: flask, websocket, uwsgi

On the client-side it is easy to use the `onclose` function to detect when the server drops off.

But how about on the server-side, how can the server detect when a client has disconnected?

I ran the pubsub-asyncio example and I can see the `redis_subscribe` function exits when a message is sent to a disconnected client. But how can I detect the client disconnect event in itself?

I don’t want to rely on sending ping like messages just to detect disconnected clients. Websockets already have a ping/pong mechanism, I’d just be reinventing the wheel adding more complexity.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/zeekay/flask-uwsgi-websocket/issues/53)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in version 0.5.3

Refer to the GitHub issue response